# Magento customer login error

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

After migrating Magento website on new server am getting an error on customer login page. I attached one screenshot have a look

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: where is screen shot

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4cff.png

Comment: Allow php to display errors, or check web server logs for error message. Without it, it's just guessing.

Comment: I solved this error by deleting URL Rewrite from the catalog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this error by deleting URL Rewrite from the catalog